# Problem With Permissions When Uploading FTP on VSFTP

Tags: permissions, ftp, vsftp

I am running a LAMP server and have installed VSFTPD to give access to my web root directory. I have created a user, let's say 'ab', and given it ownership of the web root directory and allowed it to login through VSFTPD.

I am able to login and upload files, however when I upload a file it does not have the permissions of the owner ab.

The web root folder has permissions of 755.

When I upload a file, that file has permissions of 600. This creates issues with viewing files through HTTP. However, through FTP I am able to change permissions.

How do I configure the server so the ab user is able to upload through FTP and retain some reasonable level of permissions like 755?

Answer (score 2):

You have to set `file_open_mode=0777` and `local_umask=0022` in `vsftpd.conf`.

Comment: It looks like that fixed it. Thank you! I'm surprised file_open_mode was not already set to some default value or commented out, but it worked after restarting the service.